# Homebrew Can't Link Git

Tags: macos, git, github

I'm am getting an error message when I try to link git.

```
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/git/1.8.5.3... Warning: Could not link git. Unlinking... Error: Could not symlink file: /usr/local/Cellar/git/1.8.5.3/share/git-core/templates/info/exclude /usr/local/share/git-core/templates/info is not writable. You should change its permissions.
```

All of this started after I (stupidly) installed the command line tools inside the GitHub for Mac GUI. I checked the permissions of the folder that it is telling me about, giving it 777 permissions. This hasn't helped, so can anyone either help me remove the GitHub versions or help me figure out a way to fix this mess.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I just did and that solved my issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the directory `/usr/local/share/git-core` and try again, do be aware, though, this might break GitHub...

Comment: This is a slightly better solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20648235/error-linking-git-to-homebrew

Comment: “Might break GitHub”, as in the GitHub on Mac app?  Or …?

Comment: The latter; of course the site will continue to work

Answer (score 1):

Running:

```
sudo chown -R :admin /usr/local
sudo find /usr/local/ -perm -200 -exec chmod g+w '{}' \+
```

will ensure that everything under /usr/local has a group of admin (of which every OS X admin user belongs to), and that any file with user-write permissions is also given group write permissions.

*You may still need to run `brew link --overwrite git` instead of `brew link git`, but try without the `--overwrite` first and Homebrew will tell you if it needs the flag.*

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you use `sudo` to install some application before ,So the owner of dictionay `/usr/local/share/` and `/usr/local/lib` become `root`

run:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/share/

sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/lib
```

and then run:

```
brew link git
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it worked for me. Not only that, it's a nice non-destructive and general tip for cleaning up the brew environment!